# Strange Patch Panel Wiring Guide

Tags: networking, patch-panel

I just received a new patch panel, and I am confused by the wiring diagram it has presented. I know in 568-A and 568-B wiring standards, the brown and blue wires stay in the same relative location and the orange and green wires are the ones that change. When I look at this patch panel, however, it looks like the brown wires stay in the top left corner, but the blue wires could be either the top or bottom right corners, depending on the wiring standard, which is what's throwing me off.

I've never wired a patch panel before, so maybe I am missing something obvious here, but I tried looking online for a tutorial on a patch panel that looks like this and I couldn't find one. I provided a picture of the panel for reference. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I believe it is incorrect. That said, I think your patch panel has a bad diagram. I would contact the manufacturer for assistance - however if you are in a pinch and you want to try to make it work, I would suggest using a multimeter to "reverse engineer" which pins on the RJ-45 jack correspond to the pins on the back panel, then label them yourself.

Comment: I'll probably end up taking a multi-meter to the panel to figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd love to see your results after you figure it out. Post an answer here afterwards if you don't mind!

Comment: Yup, I'll do that.

Comment: Used a multimeter on the patch panel and posted my findings.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I took a multimeter to the patch panel with cables wired for 568A and 568B and here is what I found.

Top Left: Always Brown

Top Right: Always Blue

Bottom Left: Orange for A, Green for B

Bottom Right: Green for A, Orange for B

Not really sure what the manufacturer was going for with this pinout legends, but that's what it actually is.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. It sounds like the diagram is correct other than the right side, on which the top green and bottom blue need to be swapped around. You should still try to contact the manufacturer to let them know their mistake.